# бирка на пункт меню

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

есть пункты подменю
они имеют такую струкуру

```
<div>
    <a class="name-item" href="#">еслимноготекстпереноситься нановуюстрокуотпрапрап</a>
    <span class="new-item">
        <span>
            Бирка!
        </span>
        <span class="arr-it"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

где a - это пункт подменю
span - бирка

вопрос стоит такой, как привязать бирку к последнему слову 1 строки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать при помощи float. 
Просьба уточнить вопрос, потому что способов масса, не факт, что этот подойдет вам.

```
<div class="item-with-tag">
    <a class="name-item" href="#">еслимноготекстпереноситься нановуюстрокуотпрапрап</a>
    <span class="new-item">
        <span>
            Бирка!
        </span>
        <span class="arr-it"></span>
    </span>
</div>



/*Эмулирование короткого меню*/
.item-with-tag{
  width: 200px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
/*Конец эмулирования*/
.name-item{
  float: left;
  display: block;
  /*width: 200px;*/
}
.new-item{
  display: block;
  margin-left: -100px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

[JSFiddle чтобы поиграть шрифтами](https://jsfiddle.net/jL0g9hw7/)

Comment: уточняю.
вопрос не такой простой.
нужно привязать бирку к последнему слову 1 строки. Что бы бирка плавала по первой строке  за словом которое последнее. В данном случае( на скрине) к слову "еслимногореноситься"